# Remove data undefined in popup map Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have json data, and the data is displayed in a pop up on a map
when there is a data that does not exist (Visibility), then the word undefined appears on the pop up

How to remove undefined text, so that it gets deleted on the pop up?

json data :

```
[{
"date":"03-03-2022",
"lat":-5.67,
"lng":80.65,
"weather":"2",
"temperature": "24.4",
"Humidity": "90",
"Wind": "100"}]
```

script js :

```
<script>
for (i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; i++) {
    var weather = parseInt(dataJSON[i].weather)
    var Coordinate = new L.latLng(([dataJSON[i].lat, dataJSON[i].lng]))
    var marker = L.marker(Coordinate, { icon: customIcon })
    marker.bindPopup('Date : ' + dataJSON[i].date + 'Temperature : ' + dataJSON[i].temperature + 'RH :' + dataJSON[i].Humidity
        + 'wind :' + dataJSON[i].Wind + 'Visibility :' + dataJSON[i].Vis
    )
}
```

Pop Up :

[image]

Help me, Please . . .

Comment: Regarding the old pop-up, how did you return the weather as "Cloudy" by using `parseInt(dataJSON[i].weather)` when the type of the value is a string? That's really interesting :D

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change it to a number, which will later be the meaning of a weather icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the 'undefined' in Visibility since the property 'Vis' is not a part of json data.

You can use the following code in script.js to remove undefined from the popup and replace it with blank:

```
<script>
for (i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; i++) {
var weather = parseInt(dataJSON[i].weather)
var Coordinate = new L.latLng(([dataJSON[i].lat, dataJSON[i].lng]))
var marker = L.marker(Coordinate, { icon: customIcon })
marker.bindPopup('Date : ' + dataJSON[i].date + 'Temperature : ' + dataJSON[i].temperature + 'RH :' + dataJSON[i].Humidity
    + 'wind :' + dataJSON[i].Wind + (dataJSON[i].Vis == undefined?'':'Visibility :' + dataJSON[i].Vis)
)
}
</script>
```